# Is there any program available for making bootable USB drive?

Tags: boot, usb, bootloader, drive

I just don't understand the **how-to** pages for *installing Ubuntu from USB drive*.

Is there any program that can make USB drive from previously downloaded Ubuntu ISO images?
Something like that would be pretty handy.

Comment: Software for which platform:Linux/Windows/Mac?

Comment: Just use Unetbootin as shown there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[unetbootin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unetbootin) [image: Install unetbootin] is probably the best and the easiest way to make a bootable USB irrespective of the OS you are using to create the USB as it is crossplatform.

It has a very easy interface and options to choose between distributions straightaway from the menu and to select the desired iso image.

Also,creating a bootable USB using Unetbootin will give you a very very simple and easy interface when you boot your machine using the USB.

I would suggest to use this software straightaway without doubt...

Answer (score 3):

Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3 from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ works well.  You can create a live USB from Windows and supports several flavors of Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You must be looking for [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). A fantastic piece of software, which is easy to use, cross-platform, and most importantly: it works.

Answer (score 2):

SARDU creates a multiboot all-in-one USB drive, CD or DVD for free (personal and non commercial use, read the license). Hard disks, external hard disks and all removable media are supported.

[SARDU](http://www.sarducd.it/)

Answer (score 2):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and [linuxliveusb](http://www.linuxliveusb.com) are best for making usb drive bootable.

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu way to burn a CD, assuming you already have Ubuntu running, is to start up the `Startup Disk Creator` and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal: `dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync`

UI: Use a tool called etcher https://etcher.io/

Answer (score 0):

There are many different bootable USB drive software out there. Here are the few choices that you have

1. You can use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), which is a great tool that works on multiple OSes.
   This is my personal favorite.
2. You can use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), which is a great tool if you are using Windows. It presents a great interface and is fast.
3. If you already have a copy of Ubuntu running, you can use Startup Disk Creator to help you. It is already pre-installed.
4. You can use terminal. This command will work fine 
   `dd bs=1M if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/drive status=progress && sync` Don't forget to point this to where your iso file is and use the drive that you want to copy it to.

Good luck!